# Listview android adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

hello I have a person object has the attributes name and idp, in my listview I have to show only the name and when i click on the selected item it must display the idp , how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

i believe you need to use `ExpandableListView` to achieve this functionality. Have a look at [this](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html) article

Answer (score 0):

Query your database with the projection of both name and id. Populate the views in `bindView` with just the names taken from the `cursor` object. Then, in `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` you will already get the `idp` inside the `id` variable.